# Dell Monitor S2817Q goes into flicker mode on MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) 10.14.5

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I have been using dual monitors (HP and Dell) with no issues on my MacBook Pro running 10.14.5 for 6 months. Dell is connected to HDMI and HP is connected to Thunderbolt.  After a few recent OS updates I found that my Dell monitor will frequently drop into a flicker or flashing mode where screen blacks out for a fraction of a second every 2-5 seconds.  Have tried all recommended solutions with no luck in finding a permanent fix.  Curious if anyone has found a fix?

I did find that a power cycle on the Dell monitor (physically disconnect/reconnect power cord) will stop the flicker temporarily
but the flicker typically returns 2-8 hours later.

Comment: Have you spoken to Dell about this?  You say you "tried all recommended solutions".  Recommended by who?   Have you tried switching the connections between the HP and Dell monitors to see if you still have the problem?

Comment: Things recommended in another thread:

1. Doing an NVRAM reset on the Mac (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063, as suggested by Apple's help desk)
2. a Factory Reset in the Dell monitor menu options (the only suggestion from Dell's help desk)